# Publish Blazor wasm and ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, publish, blazor-webassembly

We have a **Blazor Wasm** and **ASP.NET 5 Web API** in Client-Server Architecture.

First of all, we publish each project Client (Blazor) and Server (WebApi) separately.
We got two different folders, one for Client and other one for Server.

```
Client:
---wwwroot
---web.config
Server:
---runtimes
---wwwroot
---some dll and server files
---web.config
```

If combine 2 folders together and publish it on the server, depend on the web.config, only we can have Client or Server app!

**How to publish this 2 folders on the server?**

Comment: What server and how did you configure the sites/apps/virtual-dirs?

Comment: Are you asking "How do I host the Web API and WASM on the same site"?

Comment: I check out many articles about publish process of wasm and webapi, but my fault is about my projects Solution. my solution designed for 2 separate projects, and can not publish on one server, I resolve this by changing the solution. thanks dude.

Comment: `only we can have Client or Server app` no. You publish the `Server` app and you get both. The Server app will serve the client files as well

Comment: @mRizvandi `I check out many articles` did you check the docs? The `Getting Started` example on Blazor WASM shows how to create and use a hosted solution. `my solution designed for 2 separate projects,` the default template creates two separate projects as well

Answer (score 0):

My answer may save time for others.

First of all, we have two type of *Blazor Wasm, Web API* Projects:

**1. Full separate projects.**

In this scenario, Client and Server fully separated and publish separately on two different server (or two different urls). each project have web.config and there have no conflict to each other.

**2. Semi Separate projects.**

In this case, we have two separate Projects; Client and Server, but our Client is part of Server! What?! yeah, its part of server, and we have a client reference on server (normal type of Blazor Wasm Project Template on VS2019). now, there is no two different project, and we publish only Server that have Client. ok. no many web.config, no many project and no any conflict between web.config of projects.

Comment: What question does this answer? If you have a hosted WASM solution, publishing the Server project also publishes the compiled Client files. The `Server` project can have any kind of content - Razor Pages, Web API, OData, GraphQL. By default it has Razor Pages (for the error page) and Web API (the WeatherForecast controller)

Comment: This is documented in the docs and Getting Started documents by the way. The docs actually explain that you won' be able to just call the REST API directly due to CORS so you'll have to configure CORS to allow specific client calls. This is explained in [Call a web API from ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly)

Answer (score 0):

just publish the Server project man, you dont need to publish WASM project